# Prove that xf(x) is continuous with a specific case.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

We got
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\sin \frac1x,&x\neq 0
\\
0,&x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

I have to prove that g is continuous, where $ g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R, x \rightarrow xf(x)$. How can I do this?

Comment: Consider $x=0$ and $x\not = 0$ as two cases.  In the former, you can use $-|y| \le  g(y) \le |y|$

Comment: Apply squeeze theorem

Comment: HINT: $x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ goes to zero. You can just apply squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$g (0)=0*f (0)=0$$
and for $x\ne 0,$

$$g (x)=x*f (x)=x\sin(\frac {1}{x}) .$$

but

$$\forall x\ne 0\;\; |\sin (1/x)|\le 1$$
thus
$$\forall x\ne 0\;\; 0\le |g (x)|\le |x|$$
and by squeeze theorem

$$0\le \lim_{x\to 0,x\ne0}g (x)\le 0$$
then
$$\lim_{x\to 0,x\ne 0}g (x)=g (0)=0$$

$g $ is continuous at $\mathbb R $.

Comment: I would say you only show the continuouty in the point 0 and not in all real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Away from $0$, it's clearly continuous as a product of continuous functions. So you just need to show continuity at $0$, i.e. for $\epsilon>0$ you can find a $\delta>0$ with $|x|<\delta\Rightarrow |g(x)|<\epsilon$. In fact you can just take $\delta=\epsilon$, since $|\sin(1/x)|\leq 1$.

Comment: $f(x)$ isnt continuous at all.

Comment: At every point other than $0$ it is continuous. This is because it's the composition of the functions $x\mapsto 1/x$ (which is continuous everywhere except $x=0$) and $y\mapsto \sin y$ (which is continuous everywhere).